# MDADM: automount only works with dev, not UUID

Tags: fstab, mdadm

I am using Arch Linux. I have three functioning RAID arrays via MDADM:

```
~ cat /etc/mdadm.conf                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=beast:0 UUID=564fbbac:07f9bbeb:07ef9229:1d8fd77e
ARRAY /dev/md1 metadata=1.2 name=beast:1 UUID=7559b085:3b4715cc:59205fdd:12c0db08
ARRAY /dev/md2 metadata=1.2 name=beast:2 UUID=2dddbf33:26249617:ef8f8b65:c9670bdb
```

I have three directories in `/run/media` that I try to automount these mdadm arrays via fstab:

```
#THE FOLLOWING SHOULD WORK BUT AUTOMOUNT FAILS!!!!!
#UUID=564fbbac:07f9bbeb:07ef9229:1d8fd77e   /run/media/tcarpent/MDADM_SYSRAID   ntfs-3g   auto,user,rw,exec,nofail     0       0
/dev/md0                                    /run/media/tcarpent/MDADM_SYSRAID   ntfs-3g   auto,user,rw,exec,nofail     0       0

#THE FOLLOWING SHOULD WORK BUT AUTOMOUNT FAILS!!!!!
#UUID=7559b085:3b4715cc:59205fdd:12c0db08    /run/media/tcarpent/MDADM_MISCRAID  ext4      auto,user,rw,exec,nofail     0      0
/dev/md1                                      /run/media/tcarpent/MDADM_MISCRAID  ext4      auto,user,rw,exec,nofail     0     0

#THE FOLLOWING SHOULD WORK BUT AUTOMOUNT FAILS!!!!!
#UUID=2dddbf33:26249617:ef8f8b65:c9670bdb    /run/media/tcarpent/MDADM_MEDIARAID ext4     auto,user,rw,exec,nofail     0       0
/dev/md2                                    /run/media/tcarpent/MDADM_MEDIARAID ext4     auto,user,rw,exec,nofail     0    0
```

Using the commented out UUID lines, automount *does not work*. I see the drive as 'active but not mounted' in webmin, but am required to mount it, and enter my password, then the drive mounts. However, with the `/dev/,,,` lines, automount works, no password required.

What gives? I've been told to ALWAYS fstab with UUIDs and never device names so I want to fix this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `UUID` seen in `mdadm.conf` are related to the MD drivers.

The `UUID` used in `fstab` are related to filesytems.

What you need are the filesystem UUID numbers.  You can get them with a command line

```
sudo dumpe2fs /dev/md0 | grep UUID
```

So in my case:

```
$ grep md/0 /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf                                              
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=d634adc8:69deedd8:d491a79e:69aeff78

$ sudo dumpe2fs /dev/md0 | grep UUID  
dumpe2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
Filesystem UUID:          195237da-8825-45fb-abf7-a62895bd0967

$ grep boot /etc/fstab
UUID=195237da-8825-45fb-abf7-a62895bd0967 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
```

So we can see the UUID used is the filesystem UUID and not the MD UUID.

Comment: So this command works for md1 and md2, but gives tjhe followinfg for md0: 'sudo dumpe2fs /dev/md0 | grep UUID                                                                                                                                                                                                    28.6s  Sun 14 Aug 2016 08:10:57 AM EDT
dumpe2fs 1.43.1 (08-Jun-2016)
dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/md0'

Comment: /dev/md0 is an ntfs-3g partition, whereas md1 and md2 are not, does that have to do with it?

Comment: Yes, I don't know if ntfs-3g had a UUID you can use this way.  If there _is_ a UUID then you'll need to find another way of finding it; `dumpe2fs` only works with ext2/3/4 filesystems.

Comment: The `blkid` command will also give you all UUIDs regardless of filesystem, and faster than waiting for dump to finish